rqt_console not displaying Info level messages
When I use rqt_console (following this ros tutorial https://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/UsingRqtconsoleRoslaunch) on turtle sim, it shows messages with the level Warn, but Info-level messages are not shown. I found this post (rqt_console doesn't display all messages) asking about the same issue, but I tried everything that was suggested and nothing works (in particular, if I try to change topic to /rosout in the GUI, it resets back to /rosout_agg the next time I open the settings in the GUI). Any suggestions?
Note: I am using Noetic and my OS is Ubuntu 20.04.
